# Why is Custom Directive conflicting with ui-sref?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Here is the directive:**

```
directive('cgHasPermissions', ['$animate', '$rootScope', 'PermissionService', 'PERMISSION', '$compile',  function ($animate, $rootScope, PermissionService, PERMISSION, $compile) {
      return {
        multiElement: true,
        transclude: 'element',
        restrict: 'A',
        $$tlb: true,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
          var block, childScope, previousElements;
          var unregister = $scope.$watch('user', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            var value = $attr.cgHasPermissions;
            var needsPermissions = value || ""
            if($rootScope.user && $rootScope.permissions) {
              unregister()
            }
            needsPermissions = value.replace(/\s+/g,"").split(",");
            needsPermissions = _.map(needsPermissions, function(perm){
              return PERMISSION[perm];
            })
            var user = $rootScope.user;
            if(!needsPermissions || PermissionService.hasPermissions(needsPermissions)){
              if (!childScope) {
                $transclude (function (clone, newScope) {
                  childScope = newScope;
                  clone [clone.length++] = document.createComment (' end cgHasPermissions: ' + $attr.cgHasPermissions + ' ');
                  block = {
                    clone: clone
                  }
                  $animate.enter(clone, $element.parent (), $element);
                });
              }
            } else {
              if (previousElements) {
                previousElements.remove();
                previousElements = null;
              }

              if (childScope) {
                childScope.$destroy();
                childScope = null;
              }

              if (block) {
                previousElements = getBlockNodes (block.clone);
                $animate.leave (previousElements).then(function () {
                  previousElements = null;
                });
                block = null;
              }
            }
          })
        }
      };
    }])
```

**Here is the HTML**

```
<a ui-sref="addStudentForm" cg-has-permissions="canAddNewStudent,canViewStudent">+</a>
```

There is no problem in the logic of how the permissions work. I have verified that. whenever I remove the directive form HTML, ui-sref works just fine but when I add my directive, the ui-sref probably doesn't get executed and href attributed is not added at all.

I tried an ng-click, which also doesn't work.

What is in this directive that is not letting other directives get executed ?

What I have done is, take the source code of ng-if and create my own directive with an extra condition of permission check but ng-if does work with other elements what's wrong here ?

Comment: Let me read more on that. There was a priority of 600 which I removed which solved one problem I was having. Now let me check this.

Comment: @zeroflag Nope. Removing it, didnt work for as well.

Comment: I see you want your directive to behave like `ngIf`. Why don't you use `ngIf`?

Comment: I was on this blog and I found the idea to be good. http://adamalbrecht.com/2014/09/22/authorization-with-angular-and-ui-router/ 

I can avoid having the permission check function in the scope.